# Multi-Thread question: create a file when count becomes non-zero and remove file when count becomes zero

Tags: multithreading, locking

Say I have two methods `Add` and `Remove` that will be called from many threads. And there is a static variable `count`.

`Add`: increase the `count` by 1. If `count` becomes 1 from 0, then we create a file.

`Remove`: remove the `count` by 1. If `count` becomes 0, then we remove the file created.

How to implement `Add` and `Remove` so that everything works well? Assume that creating a file twice or removing the file when it doesn't exist will cause a failure. And assume that the operations of adding/removing the count and creating/removing the file are all atomic.

The only way I can think of is to 'lock' the whole process of `Add` and `Remove`:

```
void Add()
{
    lock()

    if (count == 0)
    {
        create_the_file
    }
    count++

    unlock()
}

void Remove()
{
    lock()

    count--
    if (count == 0)
    {
        remove_the_file
    }

    unlock()
}
```

Is there any better implementation? Can we do this without using a lock?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on your logic. You could use some kind of atomic for that like a C++ atomic or an java AtomicInteger.  You didn't specify the language.

```
void Add()
{
    if(counter.getAndIncrement()==0){
       create_the_file();
    }
}

void Remove()
{
    if(counter.decrementAndGet()==0){
       remove_the_file();
    }
}
```

There are a some problems; e.g. it can happen that you remove the file while the file is being created (or not even created yet!). With locks you don't have this problem.

And is the following possible: add/remove/add/remove/add/remove. Causing a file to be created/removed 3 times?

So you need to provide a bit more info.

Perhaps the simplest thing you can do is a using a lock.